# Словосочетание глагол-глагол

Tags: словосочетания

От какого глагола не может синтаксически зависеть инфинитив глагола?
А выпасть
Б получаться
В довестись
Г произойти
Д случаться

Comment: Подставьте инфинитив, и всё будет ясно: выпало жить,получается строить и т.д.

Comment: Тогда ответ произойти. Правильно?

Comment: Учителю/преподавателю наверняка захочется услышать полный ответ с объяснением.  Почему "произойти", как Вы пришли к такому заключению?  Иначе, даже если это - правильно, Вы просто успешно угадали...

Comment: Связь примыкание возможна с фазовыми и модальными глаголами, произойти лишний

Comment: Людмила, я хочу, нет, я требую, чтобы вы оформили это как ответ. Иначе ваша слава достанется другим.

Comment: Да мне слава не нужна, к тому же хочется, чтобы человек сам решил. Сдаётся, с нашей помощью решается какой-то конкурс по типу "Русского медвежонка", а я против этого в принципе, ищут талантливых, а кто-то с чужой помощью выигрывает.

Answer (score 2):

Вы верно ответили: произойти, а теперь разберёмся почему. Произойти - простое глагольное сказуемое, оно самодостаточно и не требует пояснения: Это произошло в мае.

Остальные могут быть и простыми глаг.сказ., и вспомогательными глаголами сост. глаг. сказуемого, выступая в роли категории состояния(а не глагол с фазовым значением): выпал из люльки/выпало участвовать, получилось удачно/ прийти не получилось, довелось увидеть, случилось быть рядом